# Deploying an Angular app in the IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular 2 app and want to deploy this in the IIS. I did not use Visual Studio to Create the app.

There is no sever side code running in the app as it communicates to a separate asp.net web api project for the database communication.  Essentially the working files are a bunch of typescript files and and css,  html.

It works fine serving it in localhost:4200

The problem is that there are literally thousands of files  an an Angular 2 app.

I tried to copying the files inside 'src' folder into 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myProjectFolder' and changed base tag `<base href="/myProjectFolder">` but simply nothing is displayed, no errors even in the Chrome console.

How would I go about in publishing Angular 2 the web app to IIS.

Thanks

Comment: Have you built the app using angular cli?

Comment: Yes, I did build the app using Angular cli

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a working build for the Webserver/IIS you must create a build using the angular cli. Then all the typescript resources are translated into executable javascript.

The default location where the build goes is the `dist` folder inside your project.

Keep also in mind to set a proper `baseHref` using the --bh flag if your app isn't running on domain root.

```
ng build --prod --bh /folder/
```

The output inside the dist older then looks something like this:
[image]